# What is a "circuit"

Tags: terminology

I see in DCIM softwares (phpipam, netbox) circuit modules.

What would you reference in these modules ? what is the scope.

- IP transit links ?
- fibers to peers ?
- fiber between datacenters ?
- fiber between racks ?
- fibers within the same racks
- RJ45 within the same racks
- fibers to meet-me-room
- every link that goes out of my racks ?

There is probably no official definition but what are the most common examples ?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without a more exact context, pretty much any link or connection is a "circuit". Usually, it's more on the logical side rather than each physical link.